# Hibernate querying the entity after fetching its collection

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one, select-n-plus-1

We have the following 2 classes

```
public class StagingConcept implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "stg_concept_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "concept_id", nullable = false, length = 18)
    private String conceptId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "concept", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
                cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<StagingConceptDescription> descriptions;

    // rest of the class
}

public class StagingConceptDescription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "stg_concept_desc_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "concept_id", referencedColumnName = "concept_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "stg_concept_desc_fk1")
    private StagingConcept concept;
    // rest of the class
}
```

Some of the details, such as other class properties and entity annotations, have been omitted to keep the example precise. Please let me know if you need more details. Yes, the FK from StagingConceptDescription to StagingConcept is a non-PK Foreign Key.

When I create a Criteria:

```
"from " + StagingConcept.class.getCanonicalName()
```

I get all the StagingConcept entities from the DB in one single query. But I need to get the `descriptions` for each StagingConcept. For that, I write a query:

```
"from " + StagingConcept.class.getCanonicalName() + " join fetch descriptions"
```

The resulting SQL looks like:

```
select stagingcon0_.id as col_0_0_,
descriptio1_.id as id178_1_,
stagingcon0_.is_active as is2_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.brand_restriction_status as brand3_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.concept_id as concept4_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.container_type as container5_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.controlled_drug_status as controlled6_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.effective_date as effective7_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.form as form149_0_,
stagingcon0_.is_multi_component as is9_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.namespace as namespace149_0_,
stagingcon0_.preferred_term as preferred11_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.source as source149_0_,
stagingcon0_.source_version as source13_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.subsidy_status as subsidy14_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.type as type149_0_,
stagingcon0_.unit_of_use_size as unit16_149_0_,
stagingcon0_.unit_of_use_size_unit as unit17_149_0_,
descriptio1_.is_active as is2_178_1_,
descriptio1_.concept_id as concept6_178_1_,
descriptio1_.is_preferred as is3_178_1_,
descriptio1_.term as term178_1_,
descriptio1_.type as type178_1_,
descriptio1_.concept_id as concept6_149_0__,
descriptio1_.id as id0__
from stg_concept stagingcon0_ 
inner join stg_concept_description descriptio1_ on stagingcon0_.concept_id=descriptio1_.concept_id
```

It does fetch all the StagingConcepts and their descriptions, albeit in a slightly larger result set in that SQL.

All looks fine up until here. But then it goes and tries to find a staging concept for each and every description again. So if I have 30000 Staging Concepts and 60000 descriptions, it will send another 60000 queries to fetch the staging concept for every description. This looks a little nasty and takes up huge amount of time, enough to run past the transaction timeout.

To attempt to resolve this issue, I change the StagingConceptDescription to

```
public class StagingConceptDescription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence", sequenceName = "stg_concept_desc_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "concept_id", referencedColumnName = "concept_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "stg_concept_desc_fk1")
    private StagingConcept concept;
    // rest of the class
}
```

So, the ManyToOne relationship is now set to LAZY, explicitly. And also, the relationship states that the concept is not optional, in an attempt to indicate that the relationship is non-optional. By setting that, I meant to tell hibernate that it should be OK to create a proxy object, if needed, because the other end of the relationship is always going to be present. But none of this had any effect. Not too sure if this would work.

I have also tried the `@Fetch` annotations, etc. None of them work. Even setting it to `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.PROXY)` didn't have any effect.

Comment: I think you wrote your own sql's to get the results you need. But you also configured with lazy loading. So if hibernate needs the descriptions again lazy loading does its job.

Comment: I require the descriptions every time I need the concepts. But if I perform a `join fetch`, The Descriptions, defensively fetches each concept too. I am not too sure why. I have tried to make the concept field non-optional too.

Answer (score 0):

Based off https://stackoverflow.com/a/29863982/5464931, you can do another join fetch.

e.g.

```
"from " + StagingConcept.class.getCanonicalName() + " join fetch descriptions join fetch descriptions.concept"
```

But this isn't the best solution because it still queries the entity/parent/concept again which is unnecessary.